# ¿Cómo hacer que un proyecto se conecte a una base de datos desde "Startup.cs"? - ASP.Net Core - Angular

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Necesito hacer una conexión local y otra remota para un proyecto de ASP.Net Core con Angular y añadidas extensiones como:

> -Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>   -Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

La única conexión que tengo ahora es:

```
var connection = @"server=****;DataBase=****; Trusted_Connection=True; ConnectRetryCount=0";
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Esta conexión debería permitirme actualizar datos de una base de datos previamente creada aparte de seguir gestionando una conexión automática.

Al ejecutar en la consola de NuGet `Update-Database` es directamente inútil, me responde con el error `CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.`

Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme con la manera adecuada de hacer la conexión automática "Local y Remota" en Startup.cs de la manera adecuada, lo agradecería.

Comment: `permission denied in database 'master'` Aquí está el problema, NO tienes permisos para manejar la base de datos `master`, o usas otra o pide que te generen los permisos necesarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio está todo correcto, salvo que en tu cadena de conexión, no estás indicando el **usuario y contraseña** de acceso a la base de datos.

Prueba una conexión adecuada a **Sql Server** de este tipo:

```
var connection = @"data source=[Servidor de BD];
                  initial catalog=[Base de Datos]; 
                  user id=[Usuario];
                  password=[Contraseña]";
```

Comment: var connection = @"server=localhost;DataBase=****;User ID=****; Password=****; Trusted_Connection=True; ConnectRetryCount=0";
 services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

Esto fue lo que usé y efectivamente me funcionó. ¿Pero si necesito hacer que la conexión sea remota, entonces solo tendré que poner "Data Source=000.000.0.0" antes del campo para el servido? **Ahora no puedo hacer una prueba para verificar si una conexión remota de este modo funcionaría.**

Comment: Con conexión remota a que te refieres?, a algo que no sea localhost?. En `data source=` indica el servidor de Base de Datos, ya sea local `localhost` o remoto `direccion_ip:puerto`